# How to make a request and output data from the database?

Tags: node.js, express, typeorm

Need to output a record containing a request for req.params.tag from data.tags from json presented below

```
{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"paragraph\",\"data\":{\"text\":\"my text\"}},{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"tag\",\"data\":{\"tags\":[\"tag1\",\"tag2\",\"tag3\"]}}]
```

```
router.get('/tag/:tag',  async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await AppDataSource.query(`
    select
    p.title title,
    p.slug slug,
    p.content content
    from post p
    where p.content ->> \'{"data":{"tags":"${req.params.tag}"}} \' = $1
  `, [req.params.tag]);

    res.status(200).json({posts});
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Server error' });
  }
});
```